# Primefaces+JSF+Jasper JAVAEE

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, jasper-reports

Bom estou tentando gerar PDF na minha aplicação sendo que não ta dando certo, ao clicar no botão imprimir gera o seguinte erro

```
    00:14:24,037 WARNING [org.primefaces.config.WebXmlParser] (default task-20) DocumentBuilderFactory#setFeature not implemented. Skipping...
    00:14:46,360 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-24) #{antecedenteBean.gerarRelatorio}: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{antecedenteBean.gerarRelatorio}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:28)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.jrHandle(ServletInitialHandler.java)
        at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.servlet.undertow.cbp.ServletInitialHandlerCBP.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandlerCBP.java:98)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:248)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:233)
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.util.RelatorioUtil.geraRelatorio(RelatorioUtil.java:43)
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.bean.AntecedenteBean.gerarRelatorio(AntecedenteBean.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        ... 52 more

    00:14:46,363 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-24) UT005023: Exception handling request to /antecedentes/public/protocolo.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:39)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.jrHandle(ServletInitialHandler.java)
        at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.servlet.undertow.cbp.ServletInitialHandlerCBP.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandlerCBP.java:98)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.doFilter(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:28)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:248)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:233)
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.util.RelatorioUtil.geraRelatorio(RelatorioUtil.java:43)
        at br.gov.rn.itep.antecedentes.bean.AntecedenteBean.gerarRelatorio(AntecedenteBean.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        ... 52 more
```

Segue os códigos que usei

```
public StreamedContent geraRelatorio(Antecedente antecedente) {
    List<Antecedente> lista = Collections.singletonList(antecedente);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista);
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    StreamedContent arquivoRetorno = null;

    try {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String caminhoArquivoRelatorio = null;

        JasperReport relatorioJasper = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                .loadObject(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/relatorios/certificadoAntecedente.jasper"));
        JasperPrint impressoraJasper = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioJasper, parametros, ds);
        JRExporter tipoArquivoExportado = null;
        String extensaoArquivoExportado = "";
        File arquivoGerado = null;

        tipoArquivoExportado = new JRPdfExporter();
        extensaoArquivoExportado = "pdf";

        caminhoArquivoRelatorio = context.getExternalContext().getRealPath("relatorios") + File.separator + "Teste"
                + "." + extensaoArquivoExportado;
        arquivoGerado = new java.io.File(caminhoArquivoRelatorio);
        tipoArquivoExportado.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, impressoraJasper);
        tipoArquivoExportado.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, arquivoGerado);
        tipoArquivoExportado.exportReport();
        arquivoGerado.deleteOnExit();

        InputStream conteudoRelatorio = new FileInputStream(arquivoGerado);
        arquivoRetorno = new DefaultStreamedContent(conteudoRelatorio, "application/" + extensaoArquivoExportado,
                "Teste" + "." + extensaoArquivoExportado);
    } catch (JRException e) {
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return arquivoRetorno;
}
```

Botão:

```
<p:commandButton value="Imprimir" ajax="false" action="#{antecedenteBean.gerarRelatorio}" target="_blank" rendered="#{protocoloBean.validacao}" style="width:150px;height:30px;"  />
```

Comment: O caminho do arquivo é legivel? Tenta testar com new File pra ver se ta OK ..

Comment: Qual arquivo que você fala? O .Jasper ou o PDF?

Comment: No PDF .. Pra ver se encontra o arquivo.. Pode ser em uma classe normal mesmo.. Dica: insere um breakpoint nesses métodos e executa a sua IDE por meio do debug, assim mostra o ponto que esta dando esse NullpointerException

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: As formas que já gerei PDF foram retornando um StreamContent e usando o componente de download.. Tentou com eles? Usando o Jasper pra ler o arquivo ,preencher ele e retornar um streamcontent dele pro componente de download..

Comment: Bem consegui resolver o problema, tava usando uma versão do jasper antiga, atualizei a versão, organizei as dependências, e funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Opa , que bom que conseguiu \o/